# Asp.net core 3.1 mvc ajax send List<List<string>> to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have to pass `List<List<string>>` to my controller and read data from it but I am unable to do it. I think that i am sending data wrongly or readuíng it badly but I was unable to find out where is problem.

My code in controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetFindResults(string TableName, List<List<string>> AllData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(AllData[0][1]); //error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
            //doing long code, problem is not in return
            return Json(new { pocetfound = found.Count(), listfound = found });
        }
```

My code in View(Ajax):

```
            var EndSender = []; //Always is like [["one", "two", "three", "four"], ["One2", "Two2", "Three2", "Four2"]] after for loops
            var TableFilter = document.getElementById("TableNN111");
            for (var i = 1, row; row = TableFilter.rows[i]; i++) { //i = 1, because I dont want to read header of my table
                var tempArr = [];
                for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                    tempArr.push(col.innerHTML);
                }
                EndSender.push(tempArr);
            }
            alert(EndSender[0][1]); //return right value

            var link = '@Url.Action("GetFindResults", "MyController")';
            var args = {
                TableName: '@ViewBag.TableName',
                AllData: EndSender
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: link,
                data: args,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.pocetfound);
                    $("#HidenLink").val(data.pocetfound);
                },
                error: function () { //after error in controller it throws this
                    alert("Error. Kontaktujte správce.");
                    return;
                }
            });
```

So basically I am trying to send EndSender that is `List<List<string>>` and then I want to read from it but I am for some reason unable to, am I sending data wrongly? Am I rerading it wrongly?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:
I am testing it and it seems like it recognizes that I have sent `List<List<string>>` but is unble to read from `List<List<string>(<-- this List that holds string is unable toread but knows that there is List<string>)>`

```
for (int i = 0; i < AllData.Count(); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(AllData.ElementAt(i)); //return that there are List<string>
                for (int i2 = 0; i2 < AllData.ElementAt(i).Count(); i2++) //is unable to execute
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(AllData.ElementAt(i).ElementAt(i2));
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
            }
```

EDIT2: My Json looks like this: `[["2010","Vše","","false"],["2001","CV","aaa","false"]]`

Comment: I would suggest you to use POST instead of GET

Comment: Ou, sorry my bad, I am going to do it :) Thanks but it did not solved the issue

Comment: Can you share the json being posted ?

Comment: Json looks exactly same as my EndSender array [["one", "two", "three", "four"], ["one1", "two2", "tghree2", "four2"]]